# Grab JSPX user input directly from a trinidad UIXComponent in my Java code?

Tags: user-input, myfaces, jspx, trinidad

I would like to retrieve the user input from a  component within my Java code. Something akin to textbox.text in aspx/.NET. I am finding the documentation very confusing and my attempts don't compile. Is there a way?

```
    <tr:inputDate id="date" required="true"
          inlineStyle="color:rgb(0,58,117); font-weight:bold;"
          value="#{processScope.benefit.serviceDate}"
          immediate="false"
          onchange="submit();"
          label="#{mb_ResourceBean.res['claim.serviceDate.label']}">

          <tr:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" secondaryPattern="yyyyMMdd"
                type="date"/>

    <tr:validateDateTimeRange minimum="#{bk_ClaimBean.minDate}"
                        maximum="#{bk_ClaimBean.maxDate}"/>

    </tr:inputDate>
```

Poor half-attempt to grab input:

```
     UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
     UIXComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("date"); //does not compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but since you already have a value binding (`#{processScope.benefit.serviceDate}`) and you have `onchange="submit();"` in your `<tr:inputDate>` it looks like you want to use a `valueChangeListener`.

You need a method to handle the [value change event](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent.html) in your bean, for example:

```
public void dateChanged(ValueChangeEvent event)
{
  System.out.println("New value: "+ event.getNewValue());
  System.out.println("instanceof Date: "+ (event.getNewValue() instanceof Date));
}
```

In your `jspx` you have to add the listener. Also you might want to use `autoSubmit="true"` instead of `onchange="submit();"`, for example:

```
<tr:inputDate value="#{myBean.myDate}"
              valueChangeListener="#{myBean.dateChanged}"
              immediate="true" autoSubmit="true"/>
```

---

The code in your question does not compile since `viewRoot.findComponent()` will return a [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). You need to cast it to [`UIXComponent`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/component/UIXComponent.html).

Also, you need to take the [naming containers](http://myfaces.apache.org/core12/myfaces-api/apidocs/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) into account. You will need to use something like: `viewRoot.findComponent("formId:date");`. In this case `formId` is the id of your `<tr:form>`.

Comment: I need to pull the date out to insert it into an error message. I inherited some smelly code. As for binding the value to processScope, I have no idea why this was done and fear the unknown implications of changing it.

Comment: Did you take a look at adding a message bundle? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15122278/880619)

Comment: You could also check out `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope()`, that'll probably hold the `benefit` object. See also http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/context/PageFlowScopeProvider.html

Comment: I am about to add a comment about the message bundle in that post.

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope() certainly works, but alas, the value I need is null.