# Overriding element style in apache trinidad

Tags: html, css, jsf, trinidad

I have a date field in my jsp page where I have used apache trinidad.
I have written the following code for that

```
<tr:inputDate label="Date From"  id="dateFrm" value="#{taskStatus.fromDate}"  >
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
</tr:inputDate> 
<tr:outputLabel value="DD-MM-YYYY" inlineStyle="color:red; vertical-align:top">
</tr:outputLabel>
```

Now, the problem that I have is that whenever I enter an invalid date the error message is scattered all over the page and I get an extra calender icon! I want to override the element style for inputDate element.So ,that it does not show any error message(or the extra calender icon). I tried to use this to override element style

```
 <tr:inputDate label="Date From"  id="dateFrm" value="#{taskStatus.fromDate}" inlineStyle="display: inline !important" >
```

But it did not work either

Comment: Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I never have problems with the layout of error messages. I always put my input fields in [`tr:panelFormLayout`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_panelFormLayout.html) tags, which could result in a more consistent layout for you.

Also I would suggest to use a `help` facet to show the date format. You can [skin](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html) it using the selector `.OraInlineInfoText`.

```
<tr:panelFormLayout>
  <tr:inputDate label="Date From"
                id="dateFrm"
                value="#{taskStatus.fromDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
    <f:facet name="help">
      <tr:outputText value="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
    </f:facet>
  </tr:inputDate>
</tr:panelFormLayout>
```

Comment: that does not hide the extra calender icon that pops up every time I type some erronous value in the date box.I tired using tr:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" messageDetailConvertDate="Invalid Date" .but it is still showing the default error message

Comment: If you want to override the default message, please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073655/jspx-trinidad-messagedetailnotinrange-for-validatedatetimerange-not-working

Comment: thanks for the coments.I am not using Maven in my project , so I placed the properties file inside package com.resources, then in I added this in properties file org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE_detail=Invalid Date and made an entry in faces-config.xml.This did not work either.How can I define properties file without maven?

Comment: Just put `messages.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`.